# Can I use my Facebook app to post on my page without any app approval?

Tags: php, facebook, graph

I try to post my facebook page via PHP but my app did not pass approval from facebook team so can I still post on my page with everyone can see the post (not for me) in live version?

I can't add page_mange_post permission to my app anymore (lost it from developer version) is it because my app didn't pass approval?

ps. sorry about my english :'(

Comment: afaik, without approval you can still post, but the posts are not visible for regular users

Comment: thank you! you're my first reply of my first question here Andy :)